# Is $2^{2^{1/2}}$ irrational?

Tags: irrational-numbers

I am trying to prove that $2^{2^{1/2}}$ is irrational, but I am having a hard time doing that. Any hints?

Comment: Haven't seen a 'simple' proof of this. It follows from a general theorem ([Gelfond and Schneider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem)). See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_constant

Comment: ...but it turns out it exists, see [A short proof that $2^{\sqrt{2}}$ is not rational](https://marksapir.wordpress.com/2013/08/01/short-proof-that-2sqrt2-is-not-rational/) from the MO question [Prove that ${\sqrt2}^{\sqrt2}$ is an irrational number without using a theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138247/prove-that-sqrt2-sqrt2-is-an-irrational-number-without-using-a-theorem)